# discord.py 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def csgonow(ctx):
    url = "https://steamdb.info/app/730/graphs/" 
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            soupObject = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser")
            online = soupObject.find(class_='home-stats').find('li').find('strong').get_text()
            await ctx.send(online + ' players are playing this game at the moment')
```

When I use the command `!R csgonow` I get this error:

```
 discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception:
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: It looks alright to me but it'd be easier if you add some debugging messages to see what's happening. E.g. save `await response.text()` in a variable and print that. It would also help to remove unnecessary code. E.g. discord since your problem seems to be unrelated to discord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector:

```
@client.command()
async def csgonow(ctx):
    url = "https://steamdb.info/app/730/graphs/"
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            soupObject = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser")
            online = soupObject.select_one('.app-chart-numbers-big > li:nth-child(2) > strong:nth-child(1)').text
            await ctx.send(f' {online} players are playing this game at the moment')
```